# Error Assigning a Derived Class to the output of a function returning a base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read somewhere that,

> A Derived class (or subclass) is an instance of its base class.

Given that, I am having problems with the following where I am inheriting a base class.

```
public class TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel : CategorisationRuleViewModel
{
    public long TransactionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Apply to All Transactions")]
    public bool IsApplyAll { get; set; }

}
```

I also have a function with the following definition:

```
public CategorisationRuleViewModel GetNewRule()
{
     // content
}
```

However, when I do this, I am getting an Error (Can not implicitly convert type CategorisationRuleViewModel to TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel. )

```
TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel vmRule = GetNewRule();
```

Comment: A horse is an animal, but an animal is not always a horse. `GetNewRule` returns an "animal". It might be a `TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel`, it might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an easier example. We will have two classes:

```
class Animal { }

class Horse : Animal { }
```

And we are trying to call this method:

```
public Animal GetNewAnimal()
{
    // content
}
```

So if we write:

```
Horse newHorse = GetNewAnimal();
```

It gives us a casting exception. This is because `GetNewAnimal` returns an Animal. It might be a Horse, it might be a Pig. Since the compiler can't be sure, and you are doing *implicit* casting, it says "I know you want a Horse, but I can't be guaranteed that it will be, so I'm giving up."

The way you fix this is by doing *explicit* casting.

```
Horse newHorse = (Horse)GetNewAnimal();
```

This tells the compiler that the return type will be a Horse. However, if at runtime the return value cannot be casted as a Horse, the system will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

---

So, to map to your example, take all the Horses and Animals in my post and replace with `TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel`, and `CategorisationRuleViewModel`, respectively.

```
TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel vmRule = 
    (TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel)GetNewRule();
```

This will fix your exception, but you are taking the risk that `GetNewRule` will actually return a `TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel`. It might be easier to return a `TransactionCategorisationRuleViewModel` instead of the base class type.